# Grant WordPress permenant access to Web Server

Tags: wordpress, ssh, ftp

I have a WordPress website that has been installed onto a Linode server. Every time I attempt to install/update a theme or plugin, I am presented with this screen:

[image]

I cannot connect to the server via this screen as the server requires a SFTP connection. How can I stop this screen from being displayed? Is it possible to grant WordPress permenant access to my web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a permissions issue, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 2bard.